# Implementing Kolmogorov-Smirnov 2 sample test using numpy arrays

Tags: hypothesis-testing, python, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

I am currently running some analysis on two data sets. One is a 'background-only' sample that is modeled as a decaying exponential and the other is a "signal" sample that features a single peak on top of this exponential background. I would like to preform a test to see how statistically significant this peak is, i.e. how likely it is that it arose from chance. I thought that a KS 2 sample test would be my best bet here. Here is some minimally working code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from lmfit import Model 
from lmfit.models import GaussianModel, LinearModel, LorentzianModel, ExponentialModel, VoigtModel
from scipy import loadtxt, optimize, stats, integrate

channel, E, counts = loadtxt('NeutronMass/twoleadportopen.tsv', unpack=True, skiprows=30)

amp = 826.
decay = 827.

#background has function form a*np.exp(-x/d)
gen = np.random.normal(background(E, amp, decay), 7)

print(stats.ks_2samp(counts, gen))
```

"background" is a function defined earlier that is essentially the best fit of the data minus the peak. My thinking here is to generate a random data set that has the same shape as my background and to test my actual data set (with peak, "counts") against it. Just to give an idea, this is what the dataset looks like:
[image: Dataset]

This is all well and good, and the code runs yielding a p value of .00227. This is what I would expect (and hope for). My concern comes in when I preform the same test but switch out the data set with the peak to one without it. Now, I am testing two datasets that are roughly exponential with no peak. Here is an example, the grey is the actual dataset and the green is the randomly generated one:
[image]

Now, my p-value is 5.08e-9 - much, much lower than before when I should have expected the opposite. I have been scratching my head over this for quite a while. If anyone could point out where I've gone wrong or tell me a better way to do this, I would very much appreciate it.

Apologies for ugly plots and any unclear parts.

Comment: It is difficult to see how a KS test--which is purely univariate and applicable only to random samples of *independent* values--could possibly apply to these data, because the graphics make it apparent that the response distributions ("counts") strongly depend on a regressor ("Energy") and therefore are anything but independent.  I suspect you're not doing what you think you are.  You might be better off reframing your question to ask how one ought to identify isolated peaks in data like these.

Comment: @whuber I am not well versed in statistics, it's true. I thought - albeit mistakenly - that a KS test was the way to go. I presented my best efforts here, but I do mention at the end that I am open to a better way of testing what stated I wanted to at the beginning. Do you have any suggestions on how to better pose the question?

Comment: Yes: consider omitting references to the KS test, which looks like a red herring.  Describe your data, state your assumptions about the data behavior (such as any models you have for them), explain your objectives, and pose the specific question you need addressed.

Comment: @whuber Thank you, I will take some time to revise this. Would you happen to know which would be better by site standards: Editing this question somewhat drastically, or deleting it and asking a new one. Again, thanks for the input.

Comment: Since there have been no answers offered so far, it is best to keep this thread open and edit your post.  If the edits render any of my comments moot or irrelevant, I would be glad to delete them to avoid confusion: they will have served their purpose.